# Converting C# code to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a small **web** application for calculating and creating billings for customers. For this, I have the following SQL Server tables:

[image]

Each month, there will be added up to 2600 new records in the `Billing` table with ~3 records in the `BillingPriceLine` table for each billing and finally, up to 750 records in the `BillingPriceLineSpecification` table for each record in the `BillingPriceLine` table. So that means a **lot** of records in total :-)

So, the initial data that gets insert into the tables each month could look like this (this is just my test data though)

`Billing` table (starts completely empty):

[image]

`BillingPriceLine` table:

[image]

`BillingPriceLineSpecification` table:

[image]

When these records have been added (I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` for that), I then have to make the following calculations in order to complete a single billing:

1. Calculate `BillingPriceLineSpecification.Production` based on: `BillingPriceLineSpecification.EstimatedProduction - BillingPriceLineSpecification.RealisedProduction`
2. Store the sum of each `BillingPriceLineSpecification.Production * BillingPriceLineSpecification.Price` in a temporary variable for later use
3. Calculate `BillingPriceLine.Production` based on the sum of all it's `BillingPriceLineSpecification.Production`
4. Calculate `BillingPriceLine.Price` based on the sum from step 2 divided by `BillingPriceLine.Production`
5. Calculate `BillingPriceLine.TotalPrice` like this:

   ```
   ((BillingPriceLine.Production * BillingPriceLine.Price) * BillingPriceLine.Share) / 100)
   ```
6. Calculate `Billing.SubTotal` based on the sum of all it's `BillingPriceLine.TotalPrice`
7. Calculate `Billing.VAT` based on `Billing.SubTotal / 4` (Danish VAT is 25%)
8. Calculate `Billing.Total` which will be `Billing.SubTotal + Billing.VAT`

I've written some C# code using Entity Framework for doing this, but when I tested it using only 10 records in `Billing` table instead of 2600, it basically stalled (for a lack of better word)

The C# code I wrote:

```
using(var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    foreach (Billing billing in ctx.Billings)
    {
        // Calculate billing price lines from billing price line specifications         
        try
        {
            foreach (BillingPriceLine priceLine in billing.BillingPriceLines)
            {
                // Declare a local variable for holding the specification total sum
                decimal specificationsSum = 0;

                // Loop through billing price line specifications on this price line
                foreach (BillingPriceLineSpecification specification in priceLine.BillingPriceLineSpecifications)
                {
                    // First, check if the estimated production and realised production has a value
                    if (specification.EstimatedProduction.HasValue &&  specification.RealisedProduction.HasValue)
                    {
                        // Calculate production for a price line specification
                        specification.Production = specification.EstimatedProduction.Value - specification.RealisedProduction.Value;

                        // Add to total specification sum
                        specificationsSum += specification.Production*specification.Price;
                    }
                }

                // Set total production on price line
                priceLine.Production = priceLine.BillingPriceLineSpecifications.Sum(x => x.Production);

                // Set price on price line
                priceLine.Price = specificationsSum/priceLine.Production;

                // Set total price on price line
                priceLine.TotalPrice = ((priceLine.Production*priceLine.Price)*priceLine.Share)/100;
            }

            // Set subtotal, VAT and total sum on billing
            billing.Subtotal = billing.BillingPriceLines.Sum(x => x.TotalPrice);
            billing.VAT = billing.Subtotal/4;
            billing.Total = billing.Subtotal + billing.VAT;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Handle error logging here ..
        }
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm looking to move this calculation process to the SQL Server using a stored procedure, hoping that performance would then be a lot better since it then wouldn't have to run on the web application. However, I'm lacking the skills when it comes to writing T-SQL, to write such a procedure.

Is there anyone who can give me a starting point writing this procedure? :-) And/or enlighten me with even better ways of solving this problem. It'll be greatly appreciated to get some feedback on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please put here input table sample data and expected output data

Comment: Your code seems to read for each line in billing, go through each line in BillingPriceLineSpecification and then get that total.  But you're recalculating that total every time for each line, when theres no filter so it wouldn't change.....

Comment: @BugFinder yes, that's the expected behavior :-) each billings `SubTotal`, `VAT`, and `Total` should be calculated respectively.

Comment: but the total wont change, theres no filter for that specificationsSum ... so. I guess I don't get it

Comment: @BugFinder no filter should be needed :-) the three tables is filled with **some** data each month and then I have to calculate the rest of the data/columns based on those initial data to "complete" each billing setting the SubTotal, VAT and Total. Makes sense?

Comment: No, because you could calculate that value at the start, once, and be a lot more efficient. the table isn't changing

Comment: I may need to dye my hair blonde as I'm clearly missing the point.

Comment: @BugFinder give me a second, I'll update my post with the initial data that gets inserted every month, hopefuly that'll make sense :-D

Comment: No, cos your codes going to run in say 3 minutes. if the code in that table isn't being changed by your code, then chances of it changing are incredibly small especially as by calculating specificationsSum  once, you could just do a mass update and have done with it in seconds

Comment: @BugFinder just updated my post with code and initial SQL data before calculations. Thing is, I can't just perform the specificationsSum **one** time because it needs to be done for each and every `BillingPriceLine` on a single `Billing`, that's just strict business rules, I'm afraid ;-)

Comment: Ah but you aren't restricting the billingpriceline to just that line of billing code, it seems to be doing the entire table each and every time

Comment: @BugFinder think I need to dye **my** hair now ;-) Thing is, the `BillingPriceLine` table _depends_ on calculations done on it's related `BillingPriceLineSpecification` and the `Billing` table _depends_ on calculations done on the related `BillingPriceLine` table, so that's the reason for the nested loops :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try querying ONLY the data required and get all of it at one time (including child collections) and then make the calculations from the data in memory.

---

Here is some sample code of how I have used SQL and SqlBulkCopy to do bulk updating of data from C# without a SP.

First you create a custom object (per table) that holds the data that will be updated.

```
// custom object
public sealed class CustomObjectWithUpdatedValues
{
    public int BillingID { get; set; }
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Field3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Field4 { get; set; }
    public decimal Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use the following code to first insert into a new table via SqlBulkCopy. Then I generate an SQL statement to do the bulk update of the live data and then drop the new table.

```
// do all your calculations and write the data to be updated to a custom object
List<CustomObjectWithUpdatedValues> DataToUpdateList = GetDataToUpdate();

// create a transaction scope incase something fails we can rollback
using (TransactionScope tranScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection_string"))
    {
        // open the connnection
        conn.Open();

        // create a table to temporarily hold the data to update
        string strTableName = "temp_BulkUpdateBillings";
        SqlCommand cmdCreateTable = new SqlCommand
            (
                "CREATE TABLE " + strTableName + " " +
                    "(" +
                        "BillingID int NOT NULL, " +
                        "Field1 int NOT NULL, " +
                        "Field2 int NOT NULL, " +
                        "Field3 decimal(19, 4) NOT NULL, " +
                        "Field4 decimal(19, 4) NOT NULL, " +
                        "Field5 decimal(19, 4) NOT NULL " +
                    ")"
            , conn);
        cmdCreateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // do sql bulk copy to insert data into new table
        using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(DataToUpdateList, "BillingID", "Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5"))
            {
                bcp.DestinationTableName = strTableName;
                bcp.BatchSize = 1000;
                bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 300;
                bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }

        // update the live records
        SqlCommand cmdBulkUpdate = new SqlCommand
            (
                "UPDATE Billings SET " +
                    "Field1 = temp.Field1, " +
                    "Field2 = temp.Field2, " +
                    "Field3 = temp.Field3, " +
                    "Field4 = temp.Field4, " +
                    "Field5 = temp.Field5 " +
                "FROM " + strTableName + " as temp " +
                "WHERE Billings.ID = temp.BillingID"
            , conn);
        cmdBulkUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // drop the table
        SqlCommand cmdDropTable = new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE " + strTableName, conn);
        cmdDropTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // complete the transaction scope
    tranScope.Complete();
}
```

The `ObjectReader` class is from the [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) library.

Hope that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your answer :-) it makes sense, but even then, I would have to update each `BillingPriceLineSpecification`s `Production` field, each `BillingPriceLine`s `Production`, `Price`,  and `TotalPrice` etc, so I guess that makes for a lot of calls to the database anyway? I don't think it's the actual calculation that causes the stress, but rather updating the large amount of records in one go using `ctx.SaveChanges()` after every `Billing` is calculated and updated.

Comment: Entity framework is horrible for bulk operations. If u insist on using EF then u need to insert using SqlBlulkCopy into a temp table and update using an sql query/sp with join.

Comment: Not insiting on using EF :-) that's why I was looking to create a stored procedure for this. I'll have to dig into using SqlBulkCopy for updating a litle further, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @Billing Table
(
     ID                     Int Identity(514789,1) Primary Key
    ,SubTotal               Numeric(38,10)
    ,Vat                    Numeric(38,10)
    ,Total                  Numeric(38,10)
    ,Status                 Varchar(100)
)

Declare @BillingPriceLine Table
(
     ID                     Int Identity(24527,1) Primary Key
    ,BillingID              Int
    ,Product                Varchar(100) Null
    ,FinancialID            Int
    ,Production             Numeric(38,10)
    ,Unit                   Varchar(100)
    ,Price                  Numeric(38,10)
    ,Share                  Numeric(38,10)
    ,TotalPrice             Numeric(38,10)
)

Declare @BillingPriceLineSpecification Table
(
     ID                     Int Identity(2447820,1) Primary Key
    ,BillingPriceLineID     Int
    ,Production             Numeric(38,10)
    ,EstimatedProduction    Numeric(38,10)
    ,RealisedProduction     Numeric(38,10)
    ,Unit                   Varchar(100)
    ,Price                  Numeric(38,10)
    ,Created                Datetime
    ,Time                   Datetime
)

Insert Into @Billing(SubTotal,Vat,Total) Values
 (Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)
,(Null,Null,Null)

Insert Into @BillingPriceLine(BillingID,FinancialID,Production,Unit,Price,Share,TotalPrice) Values
 (514789,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514789,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514789,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514789,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514789,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514790,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514790,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514790,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514790,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514790,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514791,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514791,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514791,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514791,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514791,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514792,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)
,(514792,1234,Null,'kWh',Null,50.00,Null)

Insert Into @BillingPriceLineSpecification(BillingPriceLineID,Production,EstimatedProduction,RealisedProduction,Unit,Price,Created,Time) Values
 (24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')
,(24527,0.00,2.00,4.00,'kWh',0.30,'2015-07-30 18:09:34.000','2015-07-30 18:09:34.000')

-------- above one only table preparation -----

Update  bpls
Set     bpls.Production = Abs(bpls.EstimatedProduction - bpls.RealisedProduction)
From    @BillingPriceLineSpecification As bpls

Update  bpl
Set      bpl.Production = bpls.Production
        ,bpl.Price = (bpls.SumProduction / bpls.Production)
        ,bpl.TotalPrice = (bpls.Production * (bpls.SumProduction / bpls.Production) * bpl.Share) / 100
From    @BillingPriceLine As bpl
        Join
        (
            Select   bpls.BillingPriceLineID
                    ,Sum(bpls.Production) As Production
                    ,Sum(bpls.Production * bpls.Price) As SumProduction
            From    @BillingPriceLineSpecification As bpls
            Group By bpls.BillingPriceLineID
        ) As bpls On bpl.ID = bpls.BillingPriceLineID



Update  b
Set      b.SubTotal = bpl.TotalPrice
        ,b.Vat = (bpl.TotalPrice / 4)
        ,b.Total = (bpl.TotalPrice + (bpl.TotalPrice / 4))
From    @Billing As b
        Join
        (
            Select   bpl.BillingID
                    ,Sum(Isnull(bpl.TotalPrice,0)) As TotalPrice
            From    @BillingPriceLine As bpl
            Group By bpl.BillingID  
        ) As bpl On b.ID = bpl.BillingID

---- final result
Select   b.ID
        ,b.SubTotal
        ,b.Vat
        ,b.Total
From    @Billing As b
```

**output :-**

[image]